# Getting cheapest products in categories in rails effectively

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, associations, arel

I have two models

```rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

now i want to list all Categories with their cheapest products. It is of very easily done by getting all Categories, iterating over them and finding cheapest product individually, but this does lots of queries and is very slow. I can do this quite easily with sql - something like

```sql
SELECT products.*, categories.*
  FROM products
  JOIN categories ON (categories.id = products.owner_id)
  LEFT JOIN products as cheaper_products ON 
   cheaper_products.category_id = epochs.category_id AND
   cheaper_products.price < products.price
  WHERE cheaper_products.owner_id IS NULL
```

which is ol' SQL good trick where we "LEFT JOIN" all cheaper product within category to every product and than take only these who do not have any.

**I would like to know how something similar can be done using Rails3 relations** - I am using squeel so it can be used as well.

*Observation*: I thought about defining a relation :cheaper_products on Products, but it seems that it does not help either.

*Another idea*: It is also possible to solve it with subqueries returning ids of all cheapest products in their category, but it did not let me to solution either (and is less elegant).

*Note*: I know how to do it with bruteforce (selector_sql) but I would really like to learn more rails 3 way to do it.

Comment: I know its not exactly what you ask for, but you could make an index in the db. Have a look at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem and I think you are on a right path. You could probably solve it using pure SQL query more easily then dealing with ActiveRecord as you can't avoid writing SQL any way.

One way is to combine eager loading with SQL in joins so that only one query is executed:

```
# app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

# app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  def self.cheapest
    joins(:category, "LEFT OUTER JOIN products AS cheaper_products ON (products.category_id = cheaper_products.category_id AND cheaper_products.price < products.price)").
    where("cheaper_products.category_id IS ?", nil).
    includes(:category)
  end

end
```

When tested in console

```
1.9.3-p125 :001 > Product.cheapest.to_sql
 => "SELECT \"products\".* FROM \"products\" INNER JOIN \"categories\" ON \"categories\".\"id\" = \"products\".\"category_id\" LEFT OUTER JOIN products\n      AS cheaper_products\n      ON (products.category_id = cheaper_products.category_id\n      AND cheaper_products.price < products.price) WHERE (cheaper_products.category_id IS NULL)" 

1.9.3-p125 :002 > Product.where(:category_id => 1).minimum(:price)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT MIN("products"."price") AS min_id FROM "products" WHERE "products"."category_id" = 1
 => 16.0 
1.9.3-p125 :003 > Product.where(:category_id => 2).minimum(:price)
   (0.3ms)  SELECT MIN("products"."price") AS min_id FROM "products" WHERE "products"."category_id" = 2
 => 7.0 
1.9.3-p125 :004 > Product.where(:category_id => 3).minimum(:price)
   (0.3ms)  SELECT MIN("products"."price") AS min_id FROM "products" WHERE "products"."category_id" = 3
 => 19.0 

1.9.3-p125 :005 > cheap_products = Product.cheapest
...

1.9.3-p125 :006 > cheap_products.each {|product| p [product.price, product.category.name] }
[16.0, "Category 0"]
[7.0, "Category 1"]
[19.0, "Category 2"]
```

Comment: I sort of hoped that I could avoid SQL, but your approach is inspiring anyways, I should try to have a look at it if it helps. A question: why do you join :category + add SQL which has nothing to do with categories. Would it be possible to first join cheper_products and then category? I myself tried to define has_many association to Products giving me cheaper products, but I have hard time using associations and scopes in the same time (if I want to preserve lazy loading mechanisms)

Comment: I did that in order to prevent lazy loading and execute entire thing in one query.

If you avoid `joins(:category)` and leave `includes(:cateogry)`, 1 additional query will be executed when you call `Product.cheapest`.

If you avoid `includes(:category)` and leave `joins(:category)`, one query will be executed each time when you access category trough product *lazy loading*. Same thing will happen if you avoid both `joins(:category)` and `includes(:category)`.

Comment: And, yes, it would be possible to first join cheaper_products and then category.

Comment: Is tere more rails 3/arel way to do it? (e.g. define cheaper_products as assiciation and then reuse it?)

Comment: @gorn I believe, you could create a scope in your Category model: `scope :with_cheapest_product, includes(:products) & Product.cheapest` [More](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
categories = Category.includes(:products).group('categories.id,products.id').having('MIN(products.price)')

categories.each {|c| p c.products.first} # List of cheapest product in each category
```

This won't include categories that don't have products.